# Can't compile Cowboy

Tags: erlang, rebar, cowboy

I'm using rebar for installing cowboy, but when I do (after rebar get-deps):

```
> rebar compile
```

I'm getting:

```
 - ==> cowboy (compile)  
src/cowboy_req.erl:1223: syntax error before: '{'  
src/cowboy_req.erl:226: function kvlist_to_map/2 undefined 
src/cowboy_req.erl:383: type map() undefined  
src/cowboy_req.erl:385:
   function kvlist_to_map/2 undefined  
src/cowboy_req.erl:1225: Warning:
   function kvlist_to_map/3 is unused
```

And this is what I have in my rebar.config:

```
{cowboy, ".*", {git, "git://github.com/extend/cowboy.git", {branch,"master"}}},
```

Comment: Erlang R16B03 (erts-5.10.4)

Comment: ok, solved using branch "1.0.x".

Comment: Just for future reference, the `map` type was introduced in Erlang R17 (erts-6).